# Is there a way to choose a program to open a zipped file with?

Tags: zip, windows-10

When browsing files within a zip archive in Windows 10, the right-click menu provides a very limited set of choices, and any attempt to open a file will always use the default application. Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click the file. Go to properties.
2. Click change button right in front of open with.
3. Choose an app you wish to open file with and click OK, Apply, OK.

Now you can open the file in app you just have chosen by double clicking it.

Sorry but if you want to change default app later, you'll have to follow same steps each time.

Comment: Properties only has the "General" tab within a zip archive. Seems I'll just have to change it at the Windows settings level.